# R quantmod chartSeries can't add Bollinger Bands

Tags: r, quantmod

In `quantmod` , when I using `add_BBands()` to add `Bollinger Bands`， it's show no `Close` column .  But `Close` really in the dataframe . How to fix it ? Thanks!

```
library(quantmod)
library(TTR)
data(ttrc)
chartSeries(ttrc ,TA=c(add_BBands()))
```

The error message as below:

```
Error in Cl(xdata) : 
  subscript out of bounds: no column name containing "Close"
```

Comment: I think this is typo, try without underscore: `chartSeries(ttrc ,TA = c(addBBands()))`

Comment: OK, looks like there is a function with an underscore, and it is used when the input is a timeseries, see: `?chart_Series`. And related post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8504510/680068

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@zx8754 commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76825636/r-quantmod-chartseries-cant-add-bollinger-bands#comment135439052_76825636), this is a typo. You need to use `addBBands()` with `chartSeries()`. `add_BBands()` (the underscore version) is meant to be used with `chart_Series()`.

BTW - great reproducible example!